# Dynamic layout for textview - android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am  getting number of string from server.

I want to show it on layout like below image[image]

Everytime I'll be getting different type of string. so how to create dynamic layout for textview?

Answer (score 2):

May be you are looking for a `Flow Layout`.

https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Answer (score 0):

using this code, we can able to create linear layout dynamically with inside textview. if you want, just modify the code to as you like, above asked..

```
 onCreate() Method : 

private Button[] btnAdd ,btnQuestionPalete ; // GLobally
private LinearLayout layout_button ;

layout_button = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.button_layout);

btnAdd = new Button[100] ;

 LayoutParams param2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1f);

    btnQuestionPalete = new Button[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfButton; i++) {

    linearQuestionPalettesRow = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    linearQuestionPalettesRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearQuestionPalettesRow.setLayoutParams(param2);
    linearQuestionPalettesRow.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

            textView[i] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView[i].setId(i+1);
            textView[i].setText("test");
            textView[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            textView[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            linearQuestionPalettesRow.addView(textView[i]);
            layout_button.addView(linearQuestionPalettesRow);
        }


xml code :
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         >



        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy just add the stings to the **array/arraylist** and make **arrayadapter** out of it .Then pass it **listView**  or **DridView**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Table Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) to achieve this dynamically.
but i think you want your layout in zigzag manner like:

```
------------------
  ------------------
------------------
  ------------------
```

so you can do it using `ListView`(efficient)
but if you don't want this pattern and you don't have rows more than 5-10 then you can go for `TableLayout`